# How to edit flow parameter in terminal and Is there any other way to execute the fow?

Tags: corda

I have implemented a Hotel Booking cordapp. After deploying when I am staring the initiator flow, I am passing around 10 variables as a parameter. Sometimes I am doing some minor spelling mistakes(**like chckInDate instead of checkInDate, see the screenshot below**) that are failing the flow.

Now, on the next run, if I press **ctrl + upper arrow**, it will display the previous command. 
But I want to know how to edit the spelling mistake and also is there any other way to start the flow apart from the command prompt?

[spelling mistake screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3BZo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda's Crash shell provides a quick and easy way to trigger flow and issue many other commands to the node using RPC. But that not how external applications would interact with the node. You would generally have to write a client to interact with the node. The client could be implanted with Spring Boot, and it would be responsible for connecting to the node and issuing RPC commands on behalf of the user.

Here's the documentation that talks about client implementation: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/clientrpc.html

Here are few samples that have a client implemented which you could refer to https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/carinsurance-QueryableState/clients
https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/auction-cordapp/client

Just in case you want to edit it in the Crash shell, I guess you could move your cursor with the left-right arrow keys, bit frustrating but it should work.